# regular expression regex skip special characters such as $ at the front of this specific expression

Tags: regex

I have a rather complex regex below but need to make one change to it and that is to skip anytime a special character is found in front. I've tried but can't figure this out myself. Help please.

My regex:

```
\b\d{3}[\ -]\d{2}[\ -]\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}[\ -]\d{3}[\ -]\d{4}\b|\b\d{4}[\ -]\d{2}[\ -]\d{3}\b|\b\d{9}\b|\b\d{2}[\ -]\d{2}[\ -]\d{5}\b
```

Example:

Currently it detects all the below values however I need it to skip if a special leading character such as $ or * is present.

```
123-45-6789
123 45 6789
12 34 56789
123456789
123456788
123456789
123456789-00
```

Comment: Then exclude it in all classes, f.e. instead of `[\ -]` make it `[\ \-^$]` (the hypen must be escaped, too, as otherwise `\ -^` can be interpreted as a range).

Comment: tried replacing all instances of [\ -] with [\ \-^$] but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<![\d$*])(?=(?:[ -]?\d){9}\b)\d{2,4}([ -]?)\d{2,3}\1\d{3,5}\b
```

It matches:

- `(?<![\d$*])` : a negative lookbehind to assert the preceding character is not a digit, `$` or `*`
- `(?=(?:[ -]?\d){9}\b)` : a lookahead to assert there are exactly 9 digits optionally preceded by a space or `-`
- `\d{2,4}([ -]?)\d{2,3}\1\d{3,5}` : 2-4 digits, an optional space or `-`, 2-3 digits, a repetition of the previous optional separator, and 3-5 digits. This ensures that there are exactly 0 or two separators, with minimum and maximum digit group sizes around them.
- `\b` : a word break

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yVHyHg/3)

Comment: are you able to do your magic on one more please? same thing - exclude special characters in front. \b(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}[()]?[ -](?!00)\d{2}[ -](?!0{4})\d{4}\b

Comment: @siliconmaster you should be able to do the same thing; replace the `\b` at the front of the regex with `(?<![\d$*])` (assuming you want to exclude `$` and `*` again, otherwise just replace those characters in the character class with the ones you want to exclude)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried negative zero-length lookahead?  If you're trying to avoid astrisks, `(?!\*)`, can do that.  It says to find a character that is not the literal `'*'`, match required, but it's not part of the end result.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

I assume you're trying to not match
*123-45-6789

Something like:

```
\b(?!\*)\d{3}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{4}\b|\b\d{2}[- ]\d{3}[- ]\d{4}\b|\b\d{4}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{3}\b|\b\d{9}\b|\b\d{2}[- ]\d{2}[- ]\d{5}\b
```

I tested in https://regex101.com/

Comment: just tried this in regex101 and it's detecting *123-45-6789 with your suggested regex. not sure how you're saying it's not matching for you.

Comment: This answer doesn't work—there's nothing that prevents it from simply matching one character after the star.